# javascript table tricks to hide and show division right to the click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I almost finished my code in which I am trying to show division right to the click button, as you can see in fiddle my javascript is working and functioning well but I don't know how to place right to click button and position of division is not fixed it should change according to button position, right now in my code hidden divisions are coming on top but I expect it to come right to button, this hidden divisions I generating through php

**Link to** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGCv3/)

I hope you guys will understand my problem, and sorry for my bad English

**HTML**

```
    <div style='display:none' id='id_1'>
        <table border='1'>
            <tr><td>info1</td>
                <td>info1</td>
                <td>info1</td>
            </tr>
     <tr>
                <td>info1</td>
                <td>info1</td>
                <td>info1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div  style='display:none' id='id_2'>
        <table border='1'>
            <tr><td>info2</td>
                <td>info2</td>
                <td>info2</td>
            </tr>
             <tr><td>info2</td>
                <td>info2</td>
                <td>info2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

   <br>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
        <td><button onclick="tab('id_1');">More info</button>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><button onclick="tab('id_2');">More info</button>
    </tr> 
  </table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
     function tab(id) {
        $('div[id^=id_]').hide();
        setTimeout(function() { alert(id);},10);     
        var data = document.getElementById(id);
        data.style.display = 'table';
     };
```

Comment: Do you mean to show each one inside the TD which the BUTTON is and on the right bottom side of the button?

Comment: I cannot understand your english.."but I expect it to come right to button" -you want to append it next to your button?  http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/DGCv3/3/

Comment: Yes, right to the button's td, same line

Comment: I am sorry JF it, I want separate not in same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code, you could set these DIVs absolutely positioned and use:

### DEMO

```
function tab(btn, id) {
    var offset = $(btn).offset();
    $('div[id^=id_]').hide();
    $('#' + id).css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left + $(btn).outerWidth(true)
    }).show();
};
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="tab(this, 'id_1');">More info</button>
```

CSS:

```
div[id^=id_] {
    position:absolute;
}
```

***UPDATE:***

### updated DEMO

```
function tab(btn, id) {
    var $tr = $(btn).closest('tr'),
        offset = $tr.offset();
    $('div[id^=id_]').hide();
    $('#' + id).css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left + $tr.outerWidth(true)
    }).show();
};
```

Comment: Almost as I expected is it possible to align with td block ?

Comment: what is difference between `var tr` and `var $tr` I didn't get

Comment: There is no difference except variable name. By convention, usually all variables refering to a jQuery object have their name starting with `$`. That makes code more readable. And this is because in javascript `$` means nothing special

Comment: Thank you so much for your time..once again

Comment: if you don't mind I have one more question on same, whether it is possible with position : relative ??